# why won't freya 64bit or loki 64 bit work on my computer?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit

Firstly my computer is 64-bit. I know this as I ran `lscpu` in the terminal and got this result for the CPU mode:

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

When I try to install either the Freya or Loki 64-bit versions the computer just freezes*.

My computer specs are as follows

```
CPU: Quad-Core Intel® Core™2 Quad CPU Q6700 @ 2.66GHz
RAM: 4 GB  
GPU: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] (rev a1)
```

I followed all the official instructions from the elementary website and created a bootable usb drive using rufus.

*edit
it freezes at different parts of the installation stage each time- often when sorting out the partitions and sometimes in the final setup   ; the loader stops spinning and i am unable to move the mouse

Answer (score 1):

Just because your [Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q6700](http://ark.intel.com/products/30790/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6700-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)  supports 64-bit doesn't necessarily mean that it's 64-bit mode supports everything elementary OS requires. Seeing as this is a 2007 CPU, I would guess that some 64-bit modes are not available, likely related to the graphics.

Comment: according to a review from [tigers direct](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=3241539) it supports Ubuntu 8.04.1 64 Bit

Comment: also works with 64bit versions of windows 7 and ubuntu 9.04 http://www.eofw.org/bench/

Comment: Without physical access, it is almost impossible to say why Freya wouldn't work on this machine, but you are comparing two 2009 systems with a 2015 one. That is not an insignificant distance.

Comment: the 64 bit version seems to work fine from the a live usb